# Annoying Windows Message Box with C#

Tags: c#, windows, messagebox

when you use the following code in an application to either shut down or restart a computer windows gives a message box with a warning icon that says "Windows will restart in less than a minute" and it has a close button.  any way to prevent this from even showing?

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-r");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you type `shutdown.exe /?` at the command prompt, you'll see all the available switches. You'll want `-t`

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-r -t 0");
```